# Create Service Now (SNOW) incident from Google DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, servicenow

I have a free SNOW developers instance ,and i want to be able to raise an incident from Google DialogFlow. I have the user name and reason for the call transcribed into text and need to pass it to SNOW to create the incident. I have already created an integration where i can query the status of a SNOW incident from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you can do this with fulfillment.

1. Enable fulfillment on that intent.
2. Write it in NodeJS or JAVA or python.
3. Raise the ticket from your fulfillment (use service now API make http call from your server)
4. Once you get the response, send the ticket number back to google assistant, reply to the user.

This the way you can implement this. Directly from dialogflow you can not integrate any other 3rd party API.